# Rails Merging Multiple ActiveRecord Queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

Can somebody point out how ActiveRecord is generating a nested hash out of a Left Outer Join query?

I am doing an eager load for a complex query in which different WHERE clauses needs to be applied on to the has_many associated tables. When Rails generate the query to fetch associations with conditions applied, I do not get the intended result.

I am able to construct the result in pieces - for the driving table, and separately for the has_many associations. Now I need to merge the results of association tables into the driving table.

Or in simpler terms, I have the following tables in an application.

```
Items
___________________
| id | item_name  |
___________________
| 1  | "Item One" |
| 1  | "Item One" |
| 1  | "Item One" |
| 1  | "Item One" |
| 1  | "Item One" |
___________________

Inventories
_________________
| id | quantity |
_________________
| 1  | 10       |
| 1  | 10       |
| 1  | 10       |
| 1  | 10       |
| 1  | 10       |
_________________

Transactions
_________________________________________
| id | item_id | tran_status | tran_qty |
_________________________________________
| 1  | 1       | "ordered"   | 1        |
| 2  | 1       | "picked"    | 1        |
| 3  | 1       | "ordered"   | 4        |
| 4  | 1       | "canceled"  | 5        |
| 5  | 1       | "ordered    | 2        |
_________________________________________

Adjustments
_______________________________________
| id | item_id | adj_status | adj_qty |
_______________________________________
| 1  | 1       | "adjusted" | 1       |
| 4  | 1       | "canceled" | 1       |
_______________________________________
```

I am trying to create a JSON response for an AJAX action in the following format (using JBuilder).

```
[{"id": 1, 
  "name": "Item One",
  "inventory": {"quantity": 10},
  "transactions": [ {"tran_status": "Ordered", "tran_qty": 1},
                    {"tran_status": "Picked",  "tran_qty": 1},
                    {"tran_status": "Ordered", "tran_qty": 4},
                    {"tran_status": "Ordered", "tran_qty": 2} ],
  "adjustments":  [ {"adj_status": "Adjusted", "adj_qty": 1} ]
 }
]
```

#### Please note that the records with "canceled" status are excluded.

Now that this could be potentially requested for multiple items, I would like to do an eager load during querying.

However, the following query does not work. Rails generates a left-outer join query and that spoils the party.

```
  Item.includes(:inventory).
       includes(:transactions).
       where("transactions.status not in ('canceled')").
       references(:transactions).
       includes(:adjustments).
       where("adjustments.status not in ('canceled')").
       references(:adjustments).
       where(id: params[:item])
```

So, what I am try to do is to execute the queries in three steps and create a hash or Openstruct at the end for iterating in JBuilder.

```
  items = Item.includes(:inventory).
  item_ids =  items.collect(&:id)
  trans = Transaction.where(item_id: item_ids).where("status not in ('canceled')")
  adjs = Adjustment.where(item_id: item_ids).where("status not in ('canceled')")
```

Now I would like to merge all these into a single array of hashes.

I realize that Rails would be doing something like this internally, and thought of tapping into existing knowledge than building a less efficient way of doing this with my limited knowledge.

Any help would be appreciated.

#### UPDATE

The question was in the context of trying to build a solution myself. The core problem was to get Rails generate queries with conditions applied on associated tables. The accepted answer is the suggestion to build associations with conditions (which can be found in the discussion thread of the accepted answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm getting you right, you need to iterate over items:

```
items = Item.includes(:inventory)
result = []
items.each do |i|
  result << {
     :item => i,
     :trans => Transaction.where(item_id: i.id ).where("status not in ('canceled')"),
     :adjs => Adjustment.where(item_id: i.id).where("status not in ('canceled')")
  }    
end
```

Or you can get it in arrays with a single collect:

```
result = Item.includes(:inventory, :transactions, :adjustments).collect { |i| i, 
       i.transactions.where("status not in ('canceled')"), 
       i.adjustments.where("status not in ('canceled')") 
   }
```

, provided that you have correctly set up the associations

Comment: But, wouldn't that fire two queries per item? I wanted to restrict the number of queries and merge the results, the Ruby way or the Rails way.

Comment: You can eager-load associations in the first scenario as well

Comment: If I eager-load without the WHERE clause, will it pull the entire transaction table into memory?

Comment: If you have proper associations, it should only load what is associated with items found.

Comment: And, of course, instead of :trans => Transaction, it should be :trans => Transaction.map {|t| t.qty, t.ordered}

Comment: I guess I will update the question again... I am trying to bring all items in the application along with the open transactions. Whichever way I try I end up getting all items and all transactions. If I had only one transaction table (one has_many association), things work fine. In this case, I have two has_many associations - transactions and adjustments.

Comment: oh I see, you need to exclude the canceled transactions. I believe this can be achieved with :conditions on has_many in items class.

Comment: has_many with conditions is a good suggestion. Let me try that road for a while. Thanks!

Comment: Cool! That worked. Can you please update that in the answer and I will mark it as accepted. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'json'

hash_arr = []

Item.includes(:inventories,:transactions,:adjustments).all.each do |item|
  hash = {"id"=>item.id,
          "name"=>item.name,
           "inventory"=>item.inventories.count,
  "transactions"=>item.transactions.select("tran_status,tran_qty").collect{ |x|          
       {:tran_status=>x.tran_status,:tran_qty=>x.tran_qty} 
  },
  "adjustments"=>item.adjustments.select("adj_status,adj_qty").collect{|x| {:adj_status=>x.adj_status,:adj_qty=>x.adj_qty}
}
   }
  hash_arr.push hash
end

hash_arr.to_json
```

Hope this matchs your requirements

Or you can use `as_json` and specify your own JSON format( this would be much cleaner). Check [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON/as_json)

Comment: The problem is in applying the WHERE clause on transactions and adjustments table. Otherwise all the closed transactions will load into memory, and wouldn't that be inefficient. The roadblock I faced was that Rails generates queries with LEFT OUTER JOIN when a condition is applied on an associated table. And since I have two "transaction tables" - transactions and adjustments, the LEFT OUTER JOIN generated by Rails is not giving me intended results. And that's when I decided to fire these queries separately and merge it myself. I am stuck at the "merge" part, once the results are generated.

Comment: So you want a better way to merge your results ?

Comment: Yes. Kind of. That would most likely solve the problem. The other option is probably to refactor "transactions" and "adjustments" into one table with polymorphic association and so on. I would want to take that step very cautiously.